# instagram API - Subscriptions to get notified when user receives a new message

Tags: instagram-api

I'm trying to integrate a web application with instagram API to receive notifications when a instagram user receives a message. is it possible to do with the current instagram API? i saw the documentation says we can subscribe a callback to get notified only when the user posts some picture.

Comment: No API for messages

Comment: Thanks for the response.